# How to handle "original movie" tags when there's a sequel?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was reading through the questions under the tag *independence-day* and realized that quite a few of them were about the sequel, *Independence Day: Resurgence*.

I checked the tag description for *independence-day*, and it's specifically for the original 1996 movie. There isn't yet a tag that describes the Independence Day ***universe*** (encompassing both movies).

This is a multi-part question:

- Is it okay to replace the independence-day tag with independence-day-2 if the question is clearly about the sequel? (I'm assuming yes)
- Should we create a third tag for the *universe* that encompasses both movies? Or should we repurpose the *independence-day* tag and make a new one called *independence-day-1996*?

Answer (score 6):

**It's worth having a universe tag.**

The 2016 film is not a remake of the 1996 one, but a bona fide sequel, the two ([and possibly more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day:_Resurgence#Possible_sequel)) forming a single story in a single universe. That universe deserves a tag, since there may be general questions which are about the world or the characters without being specific to one or the other film.

**But the individual films probably also deserve their own tags.**

I don't know enough about this franchise to judge properly whether both films need their own specific tags. I'm assuming the second one does at least - after all, you thought it was worth making this meta post and creating the new tag - but I'll leave it to others to decide whether or not to create a film-specific tag for the original 1996 film.

In the meantime, I've:

- rewritten the [independence-day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence-day) tag wiki, making it a franchise tag rather than an individual-film tag;
- renamed the second film tag [independence-day-resurgence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence-day-resurgence), with [independence-day-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence-day-2) as a synonym;
- ensured that all questions tagged [independence-day-resurgence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence-day-resurgence) also have the franchise tag.

Comment: In theory there should be a tag for just the first movie but given that there's only two in the franchise right now, barely any questions, and most would be tagged with it... I'd say leave it off. It'll only be a problem if we start getting more movies or questions on books/games, ie cases where you'd use franchise tag but not first movie tag.